# What do Storm Nimbus sequence numbers mean?

Tags: apache-storm

I have compiled a topology. In nimbus status I have some sequence of numbers like this

```
executor->start-time-secs <[2 2]1389244616,[3 3]1389244616,[4 4]1389244616,[5 5]1389244616,
```

What do the sequence numbers mean?

Comment: which topology you are running ?

Comment: This question is likely a better fit for the storm-users mailing list than SO because it's not about specific code you've written but instead about the functionality of Storm in general.

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII I disagree. SO is all about programming.

Answer (score 0):

In the sequence

```
:executor->start-time-secs <[2 2]1389244616,[3 3]1389244616,[4 4]1389244616,[5 5]1389244616,
```

**[2 2],[3 3],[1 1]** - represents the node. These node are assigned in `:executor->node+port{}` as given below which is further used by topology

```
:executor->node+port {[3 3] ["7693b2c4-478b-4412-a351-c558f855374a" 4], [2 2] ["7693b2c4-478b-4412-a351-c558f855374a" 4], [1 1] ["7693b2c4-478b-4412-a351-c558f855374a" 4]}
```

**1389244616** - represents the current timestamp when you are running the topology.

as **1389244616** is equal to  **9-Jan-2014 @ 5:16:56am UTC**

For more detailed information on storm nimbus, you can refer following link :

http://www.cnblogs.com/fxjwind/p/3144246.html