# What does this debug log of Storm mean?

Tags: apache-storm

I just learned storm, and tested the WordCount example code from [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java). It uses `setDebug(true)` to enable the debug logging.
But I am confused with these debug information:

```
13867 [storm.starter.WordCountTopology.main()] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus -
Setting new assignment for topology id word-count-1-1403745226: 
#backtype.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "/tmp/4ef1358b-92ce-4051-a4ce-
b33a25ace66d/nimbus/stormdist/word-count-1-1403745226", :node->host {"47fdd74b-65e0-4650-
a000-f1f0418dd7c7" "ms-VirtualBox"}, :executor->node+port {[2 2] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-
f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [3 3] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [4 4] ["47fdd74b-
65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [5 5] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [6
 6] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [7 7] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-
f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [8 8] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [9 9] ["47fdd74b-
65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], [10 10] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027], 
[1 1] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027]}, :executor->start-time-secs {[2 2] 
1403745226, [3 3] 1403745226, [4 4] 1403745226, [5 5] 1403745226, [6 6] 1403745226, [7 7] 
1403745226, [8 8] 1403745226, [9 9] 1403745226, [10 10] 1403745226, [1 1] 1403745226}}


...

14547 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Launching worker with 
assignment #backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalAssignment{:storm-id "word-count-1-
1403745226", :executors ([2 2] [3 3] [4 4] [5 5] [6 6] [7 7] [8 8] [9 9] [10 10] [1 1])} for
 this supervisor 47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7 on port 1027 with id 80043f34-85af-
4862-840e-99a58b1cf1f5

...

    16140 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor count:[2 2]
    16153 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: count __system ["startup"]
    16155 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks count:[2 
2]
    16182 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor count:[2 2]
    16186 [Thread-8-count] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt count:(2)
    16198 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor count:[3 3]
    16198 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: count __system ["startup"]
    16198 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks count:[3 
3]
    16206 [Thread-8-count] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt count:(2)
    16213 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor count:
[3 3]
    16217 [Thread-10-count] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt count:(3)
    16221 [Thread-10-count] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt count:(3)
```

What does `[1 1]`,`[2 2]` ... mean? Can someone give me some detailed explanation. Thanks very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012299/what-do-storm-nimbus-sequence-numbers-mean

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the comment, I found something useful there.
After taking a deep look at the concepts of `component`, `node`, `worker`, `executor`, `task`, I know what `[1 1]` means.

#### Firstly

```
:node->host {"47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" "ms-VirtualBox"}
```

This means there's only one node here. Node id is `47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7`, responding to the host machine `ms-VirtualBox`.

#### Secondly

```
:executor->node+port {[2 2] ["47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7" 1027],
...
```

The executor is a thread that runs spout/bolt instance, the above sentence shows where the executor is. [2 2] is the executor id, which responds to the node `47fdd74b-65e0-4650-a000-f1f0418dd7c7`'s `1027` port.

Since the `WordCountTopology` has the code snippet `conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);`, and there are 3 spout/bolt, the maximum number of executors for spout/bolt are 9 (from `[2 2]` to `[10 10]`). (1 task responds to 1 executor in this case) In addition, another executor (`[1 1]`) is spawned called `acker`, which will track tuple trees and detect when a spout tuple has been fully processed. So, there are 10 executors totally, from `[1 1]` to `[10 10]`.

- Useful references:
  [Understanding the Parallelism of a Storm Topology](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2012/10/16/understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-storm-topology/)